# select all value of checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart

i have this code for selecting one value from checkbox and added to list...by the time checkbox is fill after selecting value... so my question is that how can i use select all for selecting all values from checkbox..
i tried add select all button and take a bool value and initilize to false i setState that value after clicking select all button and change it to true ....for false i added the senario of  only selection of one value and for true i added anathor senario but it is not working properly

````
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Multi-Select & Unselect Checkbox in Flutter'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List _selecteCategorys = List();

  Map<String, dynamic> _categories = {
    "responseCode": "1",
    "responseText": "List categories.",
    "responseBody": [
      {"category_id": "5", "category_name": "Barber"},
      {"category_id": "3", "category_name": "Carpanter"},
      {"category_id": "7", "category_name": "Cook"}
    ],
    "responseTotalResult":
        3 // Total result is 3 here becasue we have 3 categories in responseBody.
  };

  void _onCategorySelected(bool selected, category_id) {
    if (selected == true) {
      setState(() {
        _selecteCategorys.add(category_id);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _selecteCategorys.remove(category_id);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _categories['responseTotalResult'],
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return CheckboxListTile(
              value: _selecteCategorys
                  .contains(_categories['responseBody'][index]['category_id']),
              onChanged: (bool selected) {
                _onCategorySelected(selected,
                    _categories['responseBody'][index]['category_id']);
              },
              title: Text(_categories['responseBody'][index]['category_name']),
            );
          }),  
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: How about accepting answers on your previous questions or at least commenting on the said answers before asking new questions. I personally will not render any assistance when I see the user doing what you are doing. Another thing, you should really pay more attention to punctuation and capitalization. Your questions is barely readable thanks to: "ending a sentence with.... then starting a new one... i should be capitalized".

Comment: okay i will answer the previous questions..